# Android application with arrows pointing to button

Tags: android

Hey guys can anyone help me how can i achieve this kind of help

http://www.android-app-patterns.com/category/context-help

it is pretty usefull for users

thanks ;)

PS: sorry for the stupid title but my original title was "android application with context help", and stackoverflow doesn't like my title :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this can be accomplished by placing a Dialog on top of your Activity, with a transparent background, and your arrows pointing to your Activity components.

Just use the same dimensions on your Dialog, as on your Activity, so the arrows match up with the components on the Activity layout.

Comment: aaaah and then getting the coordinates to the 'button' and drawing some fancy arrows

Comment: The arrows are just drawables themselves.  Basically you are just putting an overlay on your original Activity, with the new components.

Comment: My pleasure.  Don't forget to mark as correct if you are happy with answer.